# How could we say "with or by exercising"?

Tags: prepositions

> Through strengthening muscles with exercising, you should...

Have I correctly written this?

Comment: What do you want to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not; I think you probably want one of these:

> To strengthen muscles with exercise, you should..."
>
> Through strengthening muscles by exercising, you can..."

In short:

> - *with* exercise, *by* exercising
> - *to* do something, you *should* do something else; *through* doing something, you *can* do something else.

However, you haven't provided enough context to say for sure. English is a pretty flexible language, and I'll bet some counterexamples exist.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use either "with exercise" or "by exercising". If you say "by exercise" or "with exercising", you'll be understood, but you won't sound very natural.